# Syncronizing multiple exchange servers 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, synchronization, migration

We're introducing a new exchange server for several reasons.  After the introduction of the new server, and synchronizing it with the old one (mailboxes, contacts, rules, the whole shebang) we're going to be formatting the old machine, install XenServer 5.5 on it, and create a slices, one of which will have Exchange server, which again will need to be synchronized.  Then, we'll have 2 different routes to the mail servers (mx1, mx2) so that if there is an outage on one, the other should be available.

So now, I'm wondering how to synch?  I can move a mailbox from one server to the other, and I'm sure that can be done in bulk, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to make both Servers equal, the first time so I can make a backup of the original, and the second time so that they can be made into peers.

This is with Exchange 2007 on Windows 2008 R2 (x64)

Suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

See if this two TechNet articles give you some hint:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123523%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267003%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can make them "equal", you have to have a user's mailbox on one server (datastore) or another. You can't have them in 2 places at once unless you set up Exchange clustering.

I would put all users mailboxes on the origional server, back it up, then migrate everyone over to the new server.

HTH

Mike